# Построчное чтение в asyncio.Protocol

Tags: python, потоки-данных, asyncio

Открываю дескриптор (может быть терминал, com-порт или tcp) через протокол таким образом:

```
    pipe = os.fdopen(fd, 'wb+', buffering=0)
    transport, protocol = await loop.connect_write_pipe(lambda: MyProtocol(), pipe)
```

Данные получаю иногда в виде `\r\nstr1\r\nstr2\r\n` или `s`,`t`,`r`,`3`,`\r`,`\n` в зависимости от того как буферезуют на другом конце.

Пробовал завернуть в `io.TextIOWrapper` c `line_buffering` - транспорт читает из дескриптора напрямую, колбэк получает куски как пришло.

Answer (score 0):

Запускается в фоне таск, который будет читать построчно и вызывать новый колбэк. Экзекутор не нужен: `readline` асинхронный в `asyncio.StreamReader`.

Решил так:

```
import asyncio
import io

class MyProtocol(asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol):
    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super().__init__(*a, **kw)

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        super().connection_made(self, transport)

    def line_received(self, line):
        line = line.strip()
        # обработка запросов ...



def connect(loop, pipe):
    reader = asyncio.StreamReader(loop=loop)
    protocol = MyProtocol(reader, loop=loop)
    transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(loop.connect_write_pipe(lambda: protocol, pipe))
    self.read_loop = asyncio.ensure_future(reader_loop(reader, protocol))
    return transport, protocol

def reader_loop(reader, protocol):
    while protocol.transport and not protocol.transport.is_closing():
        line = await reader.readline()
        protocol.line_received(line)

def main():
    ...
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    pipe = io.open(...)

    transport,protocol = connect(loop, pipe)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    transport.close()
    # transport closes pipe`s fd
    loop.close()
```